# Strategy for isolating 3d data points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nearest-neighbor, convex-hull

I have two sets of points, one from an analysis and another that I will use for the results of post-processing on the analysis data.

The analysis data, in black, is scattered. 
[image: Scattered analysis data points, viewed from +Z.]

The points used for results are red.
[image: Regular grid of result data points.]

Here are the two sets on the same plot:
[image]

The problem I have is this: I will be interpolating onto the red points, but as you can see there are red points which fall inside areas of the black data set that are in voids. Interpolation causes there to be non-zero values at those points but it is essential that these values be zero in the final data set.

I have been thinking of several strategies for getting those values to zero. Here are several in no particular order:

1. Find a convex hull whose vertices only contain black data points and which  contains only red data points inside the convex set. Also, the area of this hull should be maximized while still meeting the two criteria.

This has proven to be fairly difficult to implement, mostly due to having to select which black data points should be excluded from the iterative search for a convex hull.

2. Add an extra dimension to the data sets with a single value, like 1 or 0, so both can be part of the same data set yet still distinguishable. Use a kNN (nearest neighbor) algorithm to choose only red points in the voids. The basic idea is that red points in voids will have nearest n(6?) nearest neighbors which are in their own set. Red data points that are separated by a void boundary only will have a different amount, and lastly, the red points at least one step removed from a boundary will have a almost all black data set neighbors. The existing algorithms I have seen for this approach return indices or array masks, both of which will be a good solution. I have not yet tried implementing this yet.
3. Manually extract boundary points from the SolidWorks model that was used to create the black data set. No on so many levels. This would have to be done manually, z-level by z-level, and the pictures I have shown only represent a small portion of the actual, full set.
4. Manually create masks by making several refinements to a subset of red data points that I visually confirm to be of interest. Also, no. Not unless I have run out of options.

If this is a problem with a clear solution, then I am not seeing it. I'm hoping that proposed solution 2 will be the one, because that actually looks like it would be the most fun to implement and see in action. Either way, like the title says, I'm still looking for direction on strategies to solve this problem. About the only thing I'm sure of is that Python is the right tool.

**EDIT:**
The analysis data contains x, y, z, and 3 electric field component values, Ex, Ey, and Ez. The voids in the black data set are inside of metal and hence have no change in electric potential, or put another way, the electric field values are all exactly zero.

This image shows a single z-layer using linear interpolation of the Ex component with scipy's griddata. The black oval is a *rough* indicator of the void boundary for that central racetrack shaped void. You can see that there is red and blue (for + and - E field in the x direction) inside the oval. It should be zero (lt. green in this plot). The finished data is going to be used to track a beam of charged particles and so if a path of one of the particles actually crossed into the void the software that does the tracking can only tell if the electric potential remains constant, i.e. it knows that the path goes through solid metal and it discards that path.

[image]

If electric field exists in the void the particle tracking software doesn't know that some structure is there and bad things happen.

Comment: Pretty! But I don't understand the goal you're aiming towards. Could you re-state in a sentence or two what is wrong with the above images and what your desired result is. I understand you're trying to "isolate 3d points" but perhaps I'm confused as-to why and what you're trying to accomplish. Without an idea of that, I can't really relate to all the specific details you gave since the question is missing a general non-technical sort of description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The general, non-technical description would be this: I have to use this data in another program. If the values inside the voids aren't zero, the other software program will produce bad results.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve this with the big-data technique called "Support Vector Machine".  Assign the 0 and 1 classifications as you mentioned, and then run this through the libsvm algorithm.  You should be able to use this model to classify and identify the points you need to zero out, and do so programmatically.

I realize that there is a learning curve for SVM and the libsvm implementation.  If this is outside your effort budget, my apologies.

Comment: Prune, I have read this several times while investigating SVMs:  

_For many estimators, including the SVMs, having datasets with unit standard deviation for each feature is important to get good prediction._  

Does this make sense to you? Since I'm only looking for indices of points in voids, should I scale my axes to provide unit sd... along individual axes or of the 3d point set?

Comment: Yes.  This also goes under the general term "feature scaling".  Each dimension in your space is a "feature".  A classic example is predicting a house price from square footage, number of bedrooms, and age of the home.  Bedrooms are generally in the range 1-4; age is 0-100 years; square footage is 500-5,000.  Many algorithms converge better if you can get these ranges within an order of magnitude of each other, such as expressing area in 1,000s of square feet, and age in decades.

Comment: An easy optimizer is to scale everything to a Z-score: within each feature or dimension, how many standard deviations above/below the mean is the point?  For instance, if the x-values in your space have a mean of 3 and a SD of 5, a value of 13 would scale to +2: two standard deviations above the mean.  0 would scale to -0.6

This transformation makes gives most machine-learning algorithms fewer shakes when accurately trying to find a central point or description.

Comment: Consider k-means clustering on that house example: in our original data entry, floor space would dominate the clustering: a 1BR house with 2,000 sq ft would be very close to a 5BR house with 2,000 sq ft; a 1BR house with 2,020 sq ft would be notably farther away from both.  If we scale the floor space -- divide by 1,000 -- then the 1BR houses would land very close together ... as they should, for most purposes.

Comment: I don't know how much this bears on your particular problem.  I suspect that you need to add a dimension, identify the "in" and "out" sets with 1 and 0 classes, and then use an algorithm that has a Gaussian option to get what you need.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I'll continue reading up as I try to apply this to my problem. I will have to some sort of scaling as the analysis points density decreases significantly in the top of the picture of the analysis data. But I understand the idea you illustrated using the house example. Thanks!